# How to call shell script from perl script

Tags: perl

I'm trying to call already saved shell script from perl script, but it's not working .

1.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/bin/csh -f

use warnings;
use Shell;

system ("/bin/sh commands.sh");
```

commands.sh:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

echo "calling shell script from perl script";
```

Comment: Select your code with the mouse, then click `{}` button to format as code.

Comment: Why do you use [Shell](http://p3rl.org/Shell)? What do you mean by "it's not working"? Try inspecting the return value of [system](http://p3rl.org/system).

Comment: Is commands.sh in the same directory as 1.pl? Maybe the path isn't correct. Try using an absolute path to commands.sh and see if that helps.

Comment: The top of the shell script says `#!/bin/csh` but you call it with `/bin/sh`, why? Also, you should check the return value of `system` for errors, the minimum is `system("/bin/sh commands.sh") == 0 or die "\$?=$?";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If commands.sh is executable, then all you should need is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system("/path/to/commands.sh")
```

If commands.sh does not have the executable flag set, then

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system("/bin/csh /path/to/commands.sh");
```

All of the other code appears to be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the shell script changes now and then for me, so I keep it in a variable at the top of the script where it is easy to update:

our `$pathToShellScript = '/path/to/script.sh';`

```
system("/bin/sh $pathToShellScript");
```

**Not sure why this errors:**

`sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching` ''`

While the following works:
system ("/bin/sh", "$renamingScript");